# Is there a way to trigger webhook on scheduled basis in GitLab CI?

Tags: ansible, gitlab, gitlab-ci, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I have an Ansible project in GitLab that runs playbook on schedule via GitLab CI Runner.

I want to move playbook execution from runner to AWX (Ansible Tower). AWX supports triggering job template via webhook from GitLab, but in GitLab I can't find a way to trigger webhook via schedule.

Is there a way to trigger webhhok on schedule in GitLab CI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the [Scheduling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/scheduling.html) feature including in AWX? It doesn't make sense to run a GitLab CI job that does nothing else just triggers a Job in AWX.

If your use-case is more complex and you must use the schedule in GitLab you can use something like this:

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: your_docker_image_containing_awx_cli
  script:
    - awx --conf.host $AWX_HOST --conf.token $AWX_TOKEN -f human job_templates launch 'Your_deployment_job_name' --monitor --filter status
```

You can either prepare your own container image with [AWX CLI](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/INSTALL.md#installing-the-awx-cli) or use some Python image and install it each time as part of the `script` in job definition.

Answer (score 0):

[The fine manual](https://docs.gitlab.com/12.10/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html) shows that every pipeline can have schedules, as [a cursory search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=gitlab+scheduled+jobs&ia=web) would also have revealed

Comment: my question is how can I schedule a webhook

Comment: Well, given that a pipeline job is a shell script that optionally runs inside a docker container, I'd say your choices of initiating a webhook are limitless. The out of the box webhook events [include pipeline changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/12.10/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#pipeline-events), but I think you are gravely misunderstanding that AWX needs a _very specific_ payload, and not just "hey, I received an HTTP POST, I''m off to the races!"